# How do I prevent this function from modifying the variable more than once?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this function to modify the text of my HTML tag when a checkbox is marked.

```js
var price = 15

function checkPrice() {
  let extraCheese = document.getElementById("extraCheese");
  if (extraCheese.checked = true) {
    price += 5;
    // console.log(price)
    document.getElementById('pizzaPrice').innerHTML = `Current Price: $${price}.00`
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="extraCheese" onclick="checkPrice(this);" id="extraCheese" />
<label for="extraCheese"> Extra Cheese </label>

<h3 id="pizzaPrice"> Base Price: $15.00 </h3>
```

It works as intended and adds 5 to the current price, but the checkbox stays checked and each time it is clicked the value adds by five again. What should I do to let the user uncheck the box and reduce the value to what it originally was?

Comment: For one, don't use the ancient legacy `onclick=` attribute, and  instead use a normal JS event listener (get your element and then use `addEventListener`). Then check which state your element is in before you call either your increment or decrement logic.

Comment: There's also an insidious typo: `extraCheese.checked = true` must be `extraCheese.checked == true`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `else` to reduce the price.

There's also no need to call `getElementById()`, since you pass the element to the function with `checkPrice(this)`

`checked` is a boolean property, you don't need to compare it (and you had a typo using `=` instead of `==` to compare).

```js
function checkPrice(extraCheese) {
  if (extraCheese.checked) {
    price += 5;
  } else {
    price -= 5;
  }
  // console.log(price)
  document.getElementById('pizzaPrice').innerHTML = `Current Price: $${price}.00`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assign an extra property to your element to check if it's already been increased or not

```
      function checkPrice(extraCheese) {
    var price = 15;

    function checkPrice() {
      let extraCheese = document.getElementById("extraCheese");
      if (
        (extraCheese.checked && (typeof extraCheese.inc == "undefined" || extraCheese.inc == false))
      ) {
        price += 5;
        extraCheese.inc = true;
        // console.log(price)
        document.getElementById("pizzaPrice").innerHTML = `Current Price: $${price}.00`;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be watching for the `change` event of the checkbox, rather than the `click` event. Then, from the event itself, you can get a handle to the element, and use that to check whether the element is currently `checked` or not.

Additionally, I recommend keeping your interaction and presentation logic separate. I.e., don't declare event handlers in your HTML, and don't include too much string formatting stuff in your javascript. Keep it surgical, just modify the specific part of the HTML that needs to change -- it will help to wrap the price number in a `<span>` tag so that you can change the number without having to repeat the 'Base Price: ' part in your javascript. This attention to detail can help keep things clean when your code gets larger.

```js
var currentPriceElement = document.getElementById('currentPrice');

function getCurrentPrice() {
  return Number(currentPriceElement.textContent);
}

function setCurrentPrice(price) {
  currentPriceElement.textContent = price.toFixed(2);
}

function onExtraCheeseChange(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var price = getCurrentPrice();
  if (target.checked) {
    price += 5;
  }
  else {
    price -= 5;
  }
  setCurrentPrice(price);
}

document.getElementById('extraCheese').addEventListener('change', onExtraCheeseChange);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="extraCheese" id="extraCheese" />
<label for="extraCheese"> Extra Cheese </label>

<h3 id="pizzaPrice"> Base Price: $<span id="currentPrice">15.00</span> </h3>
```